# Withings API: The callback URL is either unknown or invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, withings

I'm trying to set a notification in the withings API (with the withings-simplificator gem). I always get this error, no matter what URL I enter or if I encode it or not:

```
irb(main):013:0> user.subscribe_notification('http://foo.bar.com', 'test subscription')
Withings::ApiError: The callback URL 'http://foo.bar.com' is either unknown or invalid - Status code: 293
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/simplificator-withings-0.7.0/lib/withings/connection.rb:80:in `verify_response!'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/simplificator-withings-0.7.0/lib/withings/connection.rb:22:in `get_request'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/simplificator-withings-0.7.0/lib/withings/connection.rb:27:in `get_request'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/simplificator-withings-0.7.0/lib/withings/user.rb:26:in `subscribe_notification'
  from (irb):13
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:8:in `require'
  from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Has anyone encountered this and has a solution?

**Update 1:**

So I tried without the withings simplificator gem:

```
API_KEY       = '123'
API_SECRET    = '456'
USER_ID       = '789'
USER_KEY      = 'abc'
USER_SECRET   = 'def'
CONFIGURATION = {               site: 'https://oauth.withings.com',
                  request_token_path: '/account/request_token',
                   access_token_path: '/account/access_token',
                      authorize_path: '/account/authorize',
                         http_method: :get,
                              scheme: :query_string
                }

@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new API_KEY, API_SECRET, CONFIGURATION

@access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new @consumer, USER_KEY, USER_SECRET

url = ERB::Util.url_encode("www.foo.bar/trigger")
comment = ERB::Util.url_encode("Trigger")
response = @access_token.get("https://wbsapi.withings.net/notify?action=subscribe&userid=#{USER_ID}&callbackurl=#{url}&comment=#{comment}")
JSON.parse(response.body)
```

And same error:

```
irb(main):051:0>   JSON.parse(response.body)
=> {"status"=>293}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the callback URL need to resolve? If so it probably needs a valid host name that can be resolved with DNS.

Comment: I should add that all other API Calls are successful and, @tadman, I also tested with a 'real' URL, that resolves. (I can GET from it and PUSH to it with my browser.) Still same error ...

Comment: @jlxq0 did you find an answer to this ? i m stucked at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure during setup

- your "trigger url" exists
- it responds with "ok" to a POST
- it is fast ... I couldn't figure this out exactly how fast, but I think the response time should be < 1 second

With an environment like this, my code above works.

Answer (score 1):

Your notification endpoint going to do two operations:

1. it is going to respond test request response (while you register it will check your URL is exist or not). You will receive call with empty body object. If it is not have `userid`, it is not a data notification, so you have to respond status as 200 with empty body;
2. after successful registration you will receive data alert. This time you can handle by your business logic.